# Java class interacting with another class

Tags: java, swt

Class View is for user interface, it contains a big white styledtext.

```
public class View extends ViewPart{
   public static StyledText txtArea;

   public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
   //...

   txtArea = new StyledText(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
   txtArea.addText("My first line !");

   new Server("This is my new second line !").start();
   }

   public static void addText(String str){
      txtArea.append(str);
   }
}

class Server extends Thread{
   private String str;

   Server(String str){
      this.str = str;   
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
      View.addText(str);
   }
}
```

Class Server cannot call View.addText().

It would work if I make a reference to the txtArea object, but I must call addText() method.

**Edit:**

Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)

at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)

at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:359)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setText(StyledText.java:9885)

at com.project.udp.views.View.log(View.java:255)

at com.project.udp.views.Server.run(View.java:294)

Comment: Maybe you want to use View.txtArea.addText(str)

Comment: You should call thread start() method to run.

Comment: What do you mean, "cannot call addText()?"

Comment: Does this trowing any Exception? post it.

Comment: Can you post SWT.java lines 4355 to 4365

Comment: @Deepak - SWT is an open source project. That's a rather silly request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your Server class' code is not on the SWT Display thread, so telling your widget to update is an invalid thread access.

You should probably do something like:

```
public static void addText(final String str){
  txtArea.getDisplay().asyncExec (new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
       if (!txtArea.isDisposed())
          txtArea.append(str);
    }
  }); 
}
```

to make the append execute on the proper thread.

For more information on SWT and threading, I'll refer you to the eclipse guide:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fswt_threading.htm